# How To GetFeatureInfo From a GeoWebCached Layer in Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm really really struggling with this.  I have created a map using GeoServer and OpenLayers.  Things have been working out here and there, as I am new to all this so a lot has been just trial and error.  I noticed my map started loading slower and slower so I have decided to use GeoWebCache to cache my layers.  The problem is that now I cannot get the feature info to display in a pop-up as it once was when I was getting the layers straight from the server/wms.  The part that even confuses me further is that when I provide the pop-up with the URL '`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms`' it actually attempts to send a request.  However when I provide the right URL from the server where the data actually is (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms`), it's like if no request is being made.  (I am seeing this in firebug).  I've also created a `geowebcache.xml` files and have listed several of my layers as `<queryable>true</queryable>`, but no differences there either :(  Any suggestions you can offer me will be greatly appreciated.  I am truly very stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

0 down vote accept

Finally I have stumbled across here:

http://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/error_in_wmsgetfeatureinfo#reply_2612983

```
new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({

    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", 

    layerUrls: ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"],

    title: 'Identify features by clicking',

    queryVisible: true

});
```

Turns out what I was missing was `layerUrls: ["http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms"]`

This means: consider the layerUrls (i.e. your gwc urls), but issue requests to the url (i.e. your wms url).

elshae